# LDAP Users not visible in the Manage Users in the WebSphere admin console

Tags: active-directory, websphere, websphere-8

I have IBM WAS 8.5 trial version in Windows 7 and I have installed MS Active Directory on the same machine with the root dn `DC=SSO,DC=PACS,DC=TEMENOS` and I have created an user Manohar with the `dn` as `"CN=Manohar,OU=Users,DC=SSO,DC=PACS,DC=TEMENOS"` and password as "Temenos17"

Along with Manohar I have created two more users `T24User1` & `T24User2` with parent dn as `OU=Users,DC=SSO,DC=PACS,DC=TEMENOS`

In WAS I have created one Federated repository for MS AD. I have configured all the AD details seems properly. I am able to login into WAS console with Manohar user. When I try to list the users from "Manage Users" link in WAS no single user is showing and at the same time from "Manage Groups" link all the groups are showing

Please help me to list all my Active Directory users in my WAS console.

Comment: What user are you using as bind user in the LDAP configuration? Make sure that user can browse your AD. The best is to use some third party LDAP browser, to see if your directory can be successfully queried outside of WAS.

Comment: Hi Gas, thanks for your reply. I am using 'Manohar' as bind user with dn CN=Manohar,OU=Users,DC=SSO,DC=PACS,DC=TEMENOS. This user is an administrator in AD. Using jxplorer i am able to query/navigate my active directory completely. I have tried all the possibilities to list my active directory users in WAS "Manage Users" link but not able to list

Comment: Are you sure you configured your LDAP under federated registry, not as a Standalone LDAP? And that you used Active directory as ldap type while configuring it?

Comment: Yes Gas, i have used federated repository in which i have created LDAP Repository and gave all the active directory details.

Comment: This is very strange. What you have in `Global security > Federated repositories > LDAP1 > Federated repositories entity types to LDAP object classes mapping > PersonAccount` as `objectclass` and `searchFilter`?

Comment: objectclass --> "user"  and searchFilter --> "(ObjectCategory=User)"

Comment: This is correct. I've configured this plenty of times and never seen such behavior. Do you have any errors in the SystemOut.log? You may also try to enable tracing before you click Manage Users and see if you find anything useful there   `*=info:com.ibm.ws.security.*=all:com.ibm.websphere.security.*=all:com.ibm.websphere.wim.*=all:com.ibm.wsspi.wim.*=all:com.ibm.ws.wim.*=all` or create other profile and try.

Comment: there were no errors or exceptions in the system out log file and i have even enabled the trace log for com.ibm.ws.security.*. There is no error or exception. i will try with a new profile Gas. thanks

Comment: While you will be configuring new profile, try to only set host, port, bind dn/password and base dn, keep rest as defaults.

Comment: still the same with the new profile. i am not able to list AD users and able to list AD groups. If possible can you check my system in team viewer ?

Comment: First of all, did you restart the Servers, NodeAgent and the deployment manager after you added the new repository? :) Have a nice day!

Comment: I am seeing the same issue. My test and prod system were both working until recently.  Now my test system is not working, while the prod system is working (I'm glad it's not the other way around). No changes were made to the test system.